# Start activity while pulling data from database

Tags: android

I have an application which stores data in SQLite database. Main activity is just a screen with a single button. When user clicks this buton the second activity opens. The second activity is a list (ListActivity) which should contain all the records from database. Here is the question: which approaches fits better: 1) when button is clicked, start AsyncTask, in doInBackground method pull data from database and send pulled data to the second activity as a parcelable array or 2) start the second activity, in onCreate method pull the data from database and display progress bar while selecting data. I believe it is not based on primary opinion and there should be valuable pros and cons. But I am new to Android and I'm struggling to identify better approach for this. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Its all depends on if you want data to be pre populated on second activity or not. But If I was you I would prefer second option.

Comment: So, it's a matter of Ux but not performance? I'm just afraid to slow down speed of new activity loading

Comment: If its local DB you won't see any difference in the loading. But if you want your second activity to be pre popuated, use first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is not user friendly. Because when user press a button to open different activity(In terms of UI), then user except to show a transition, Not the stuck in first activity. Actually it depend on your application UX design. Also first approach has another problem. If you load data in first activity then you have to transfer many data when you call another activity.

Use the slightly modified second approach. First start the second activity, then call the AsyncTask(in onCreate method) to load the data.

Comment: Yes, my main concern is about sending big amount of data between activities. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think the best is starting AsyncTask on clicking button and process data in doInBackground as You said. In onCreate() of second acivity display progress bar, and in  doInBackground() send data and display items. It seems to be the best from point of performance.

Comment: How exactly would it affect performance? Its just the UI experience.

Comment: Before onCreate() method is invoked, some thinks happens and some time passes. If You start AsyncTask earlier in first acivity, You should obtain result faster. At least I think so.

Comment: local DB operation wouldn't show any significant difference. If it was an external call then I would agree with you.

Comment: Well, it depends how you define "significant" difference. It's probably not observable advantage, but I believe that in big applications each difference matter.